# Moving Variables from JS to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am currently attempting to move a variable from JS to PHP.

They are being used for Stripe.

I understand I may have to use AJAX?

```
function _goAheadWithCustomerId(c) {
  console.log('Customer Id is :', c);
  customerId = c; }
```

I want to move customerId to a PHP file.

How might I do that?

Comment: jQuery and `$.ajax` perhaps?

Comment: Do you know how? @tadman

Comment: If you're using jQuery that's the way to go about it. If not, you could always do it the hard way, but in either case you need to *try something* and we can help you with your incomplete or partial solution. What you have here isn't quite enough, we don't know what variable is being moved and to what PHP destination it's going, even in rough terms.

Answer (score 0):

Well the easiest way i can think of without using AJAX is just send a get request to a php page using

```
window.location.href
```

Code for JS

```
function _goAheadWithCustomerId(c) {
  console.log('Customer Id is :', c);
  customerId = c; 
  window.location.href = "index.php?customerid=" + c;
}
```

And later using php check `if(isset($_GET["customerid"]` to check if the value has been received or not.

Php Code

```
if(isset($_GET["customerid"]))
{
    $c = $_GET["customerid"];
    // use it the way you want.
}
```

Comment: Would that work in the same document? I am looking to do it all in one page. Thanks for the quick reply @Parth!

Comment: `window.location.href= 'filename.php?var='+var;` going to try this! Thanks!

Comment: Is that what you meant? What would the php look like?

Comment: This leads to an infinite refresh loop... @Parth

Comment: How are you calling your function? Call the function on an event? I tried it its working fine for me.

Comment: I added it to an async function. Could that be it?

Comment: No, that won't work in one page.  `window.location` does not work in the background; it refreshes the page.  You have to use ajax if you don't want a page refresh.

Comment: @BryanSanders yes

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code in AJAX.

```
function sendCustId(c) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("custDiv").innerHTML = "Customer ID successfully sent to server.";
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "myPhpScript.php?custId="+c, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

At server side you need to access variable as

```
$customerId = $_REQUEST['custId'];
```

Comment: Perhaps the documents are both being included in one document? Or is it in an async function?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include argument.